# How to generate a custom ID in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$cc = $this->db->count_all('job_card');
$coun = str_pad($cc,4,STR_PAD_LEFT);
$id = "JI"."-";
$d = date('y') ;
$mnth = date("m"); 
$customid = $id.$d.$mnth.$coun;
```

I am generating and ID of "JI-18051000", but I need it to generate "JI-18050001".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the third parameter of [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) which indicates what should be used for the padding.

In this case, you want to add `0`, so you need to add that to your code:

```
$cc = $this->db->count_all('job_card');
$coun = str_pad($cc, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT); // Updated line to include '0'
$id = "JI"."-";
$d = date('y') ;
$mnth = date("m");
$customid = $id.$d.$mnth.$coun;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use the following line:
$coun = str_pad($cc,4,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
```